# Spring AuditorAware with custom User Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am currently adding Auditing to my Entities. That is working fine but i want to save the Id of the User which is related to the Entity inside the @CreatedBy and @LastModifiedBy Columns and not the Name which i have right now.

I am also using Spring Security + JWT to get the User which is working fine.

How can i achieve this with the following Configuration?

User Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "UserSequence")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UserSequence",
            strategy = "com.simagdo.crmAPI.utils.SequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "130"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d")
            }
    )
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String id;
    @Column(
            name = "UserName",
            length = 80,
            unique = true)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

}
```

AuditorAware:

```
public class AuditAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of("Simagdo");
    }
}
```

The config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
        return new AuditAwareImpl();
    }

}
```

My Auditable Class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @CreatedBy
    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE
            }
    )
    private User createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(
            name = "CreatedDate",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false
    )
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @LastModifiedBy
    @OneToOne(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE
            }
    )
    private User lastModifiedBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(
            name = "LastModifiedDate",
            nullable = false
    )
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding following on top of entity class that contains `@CreatedBy` & `@LastModifiedBy`:

```
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
```